# Target iFrame window object with jQuery

Tags: jquery

All the examples I see are using regular javascript, like this:

```
frames[index].window
```

I tried:

```
$("iframe").window
```

and

```
$("iframe")[0].window
```

but it returns `undefined`

How do I target an iFrame window object like javascript, but in jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the [iframe's window](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_frame_contentwindow.asp) by using the `contentWindow` property of the iframe:

```
$("iframe")[0].contentWindow
```

Comment: No problem. glad to help.

Comment: For me it was $("#id")[0].contentWindow.  However $("#id"').contentWindow failed, without the [0]. I forgot that $(selector)[0] is the DOM object, but without [0] it is a collection of jQuery objects, even if there is only one.